# My list is coming out undefined for all values when parsing with JSON? Why?

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

New to this. So im printing a list. Im getting names from a button. All the names are coming out as undefined? It's something im doing with localstorage im sure. Idk what tho.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script>
    function passVal() {
    newList = [];
    var newName = document.getElementById("addname").value;
    addedNamesList = newList.push(newName);
    localStorage.setItem("newList1", JSON.stringify(addedNamesList));
    var LL = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newList1"));
    document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML += "<li>" + LL[LL.length-1] + "</li>";
    }
    </script>
    <ul id="nameList"></ul>

    {% extends "navigation.html" %}
    {% block content %}

    <p> Add a name: </p>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <form action="home.html">
    <input type='text' input name='name' id='addname'>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Submit" onclick="passVal()">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
    <title> Add Name Page </title>

</head>


  <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is everything inside the `head` tag?

Comment: Although this is not an issue, but wanted to point out, the best practice is to put `script` tags just before the closing `body` tag rather than in the `head` section of your HTML. The reason for this is that HTML loads from top to bottom.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments. Im honestly doing this all as I go. I had a flask, html assignment that basically is self learn at this point. I had a week to learn the basics of html, css, and javascript. D: that's school for you. But thank you for all the advice. I'll move things around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(addedNamesList)` should be `JSON.stringify(newList)`. The `push()` method doesn't return a new list, it modifies the list in place and returns the length of the list. So you're storing `1` in local storage, not the list.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try what you mentioned. I didn't know that. I thought it was doing the former. Like i told people above, I'm learning javascript on the spot for my assignment. Thanks again